# UIActivityViewController rotation problems

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am having problem with the UIActivityViewController, I instantiate a new instance each time user presses the 'share' button, but it will not rotate properly. Is my code lacking something essential?

When I rotate only the status bar and  the UIActivityViewController will rotate (not the view in the background) and also sometimes the activityView´s size will be wrong.

```
    UIActivityViewController *activityVC;
    // Init sharing items and View Controller
    NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@""];

    UIImage *imageToShare = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName"];
    NSArray *postItems = @[message, imageToShare];

    activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]
                   initWithActivityItems:postItems
                   applicationActivities:nil];


    [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:^() {
        [activityVC setCompletionHandler:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed) {
            // Completed
        }];
    }];
```

Comment: What do you have in the root View controller set for:
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your question you have a view which is not rotating, right?. In that case all you need to do is to place this code in the View Controller `UIActivityViewController` is in:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown;
}
```

In `- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations` I have placed `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait`
and
`UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown` for you and that will make the view able to rotate only when you place the device upside-down, but you can add
`UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft`
and/or
`UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight` to let the the view rotate in all orientations.

I hope my answer will help you, if not can you explain your situation better to me?
Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

if anyone run into similar issue with `UIActivityViewController` try implementing this function in your app delegate and return the supported orientations.

`- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {
}`